# Scala: Object XXX is not a member of package XXX

Tags: java, scala, joern

Environment:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I was using Joern (a scala program) to run a scala script (graph-for-funcs.sc) on ubuntu-20.04, in the joern interactive shell, I used a cmd like:

```
joern> cpg.runScript("graph-for-funcs.sc")
```

I ran into to the issue:

```
"graph-for-funcs.sc:33: object dataflowengine is not a member of package io.shiftleft"
```

But when I used Joern with the same script on `Ubuntu-18.04`, it worked. Can anyone give me some hints why this happened? I am not familiar with scala as well as java, is that because some path variables I haven't configured?

the joern program work tree:

```
joern/
├── graph-for-funcs.sc
└── joern-cli
    ├── bin
    │   ├── ammonite-bridge
    │   ├── ammonite-bridge.bat
    │   ├── cpg-2-scpg
    │   ├── cpg-2-scpg.bat
    │   ├── fuzzyc-2-cpg
    │   ├── fuzzyc-2-cpg.bat
    │   ├── fuzzyppcli
    │   ├── joern-parse
    │   ├── joern-parse.bat
    │   └── scalac
    ├── conf
    │   └── log4j2.xml
    ├── fuzzyc2cpg.sh
    ├── joern
    ├── joern-cpg2scpg
    ├── joern-parse
    ├── lib
    │   ├── au.com.bytecode.opencsv-2.4.jar
    │   ├── com.carrotsearch.hppc-0.7.1.jar
    │   ├── com.chuusai.shapeless_2.13-2.3.3.jar
    │   ├── com.github.javaparser.javaparser-core-3.2.5.jar
    │   ├── com.github.pathikrit.better-files_2.13-3.8.0.jar
    │   ├── com.github.scopt.scopt_2.13-3.7.1.jar
    │   ├── com.google.guava.guava-21.0.jar
    │   ├── com.google.protobuf.protobuf-java-3.10.0.jar
    │   ├── com.h2database.h2-mvstore-1.4.199.jar
    │   ├── com.jcabi.jcabi-aspects-0.17.1.jar
    │   ├── com.jcabi.jcabi-log-0.14.3.jar
    │   ├── com.jcabi.jcabi-manifests-1.1.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite_2.13.0-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite-interp_2.13.0-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite-interp-api_2.13.0-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite-ops_2.13-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite-repl_2.13.0-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite-repl-api_2.13.0-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite-runtime_2.13.0-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite-terminal_2.13-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ammonite-util_2.13-2.0.4.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.fansi_2.13-0.2.8.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.fastparse_2.13-2.2.3.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.geny_2.13-0.5.0.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.os-lib_2.13-0.6.3.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.pprint_2.13-0.5.8.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.requests_2.13-0.5.0.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.scalaparse_2.13-2.2.3.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.sourcecode_2.13-0.2.0.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ujson_2.13-0.9.8.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.upack_2.13-0.9.8.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.upickle_2.13-0.9.8.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.upickle-core_2.13-0.9.8.jar
    │   ├── com.lihaoyi.upickle-implicits_2.13-0.9.8.jar
    │   ├── com.massisframework.j-text-utils-0.3.4.jar
    │   ├── com.michaelpollmeier.gremlin-scala_2.13-3.4.4.5.jar
    │   ├── com.michaelpollmeier.macros_2.13-3.4.4.5.jar
    │   ├── commons-cli.commons-cli-1.4.jar
    │   ├── commons-collections.commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
    │   ├── commons-configuration.commons-configuration-1.10.jar
    │   ├── commons-io.commons-io-2.5.jar
    │   ├── commons-lang.commons-lang-2.6.jar
    │   ├── com.squareup.javapoet-1.8.0.jar
    │   ├── com.thoughtworks.paranamer.paranamer-2.8.jar
    │   ├── io.circe.circe-core_2.13-0.12.2.jar
    │   ├── io.circe.circe-generic_2.13-0.12.2.jar
    │   ├── io.circe.circe-jawn_2.13-0.12.2.jar
    │   ├── io.circe.circe-numbers_2.13-0.12.2.jar
    │   ├── io.circe.circe-parser_2.13-0.12.2.jar
    │   ├── io.get-coursier.interface-0.0.8.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph_2.13-0.11.287.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph-protos_2.13-0.11.287.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.console_2.13-0.11.287.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.dataflowengineoss_2.13-0.11.287.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.fuzzyc2cpg_2.13-1.1.45.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.joern-cli-9c0397efa3eb6787d7dd1ae104bab1379a6816e8.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.overflowdb-tinkerpop3-0.94.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.overflowdb-traversal_2.13-0.94.jar
    │   ├── io.shiftleft.semanticcpg_2.13-0.11.287.jar
    │   ├── javax.validation.validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
    │   ├── jline.jline-2.14.6.jar
    │   ├── net.java.dev.jna.jna-4.2.2.jar
    │   ├── net.objecthunter.exp4j-0.4.8.jar
    │   ├── net.sf.trove4j.core-3.1.0.jar
    │   ├── org.antlr.antlr4-runtime-4.7.2.jar
    │   ├── org.apache.commons.commons-lang3-3.9.jar
    │   ├── org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-api-2.13.3.jar
    │   ├── org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-core-2.13.3.jar
    │   ├── org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.3.jar
    │   ├── org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin-core-3.4.4.jar
    │   ├── org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin-shaded-3.4.4.jar
    │   ├── org.aspectj.aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar
    │   ├── org.javassist.javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar
    │   ├── org.javatuples.javatuples-1.2.jar
    │   ├── org.jline.jline-reader-3.6.2.jar
    │   ├── org.jline.jline-terminal-3.6.2.jar
    │   ├── org.jline.jline-terminal-jna-3.6.2.jar
    │   ├── org.json4s.json4s-ast_2.13-3.6.7.jar
    │   ├── org.json4s.json4s-core_2.13-3.6.7.jar
    │   ├── org.json4s.json4s-native_2.13-3.6.7.jar
    │   ├── org.json4s.json4s-scalap_2.13-3.6.7.jar
    │   ├── org.msgpack.msgpack-core-0.8.17.jar
    │   ├── org.reflections.reflections-0.9.12.jar
    │   ├── org.scala-lang.modules.scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.1.3.jar
    │   ├── org.scala-lang.modules.scala-collection-contrib_2.13-0.2.1.jar
    │   ├── org.scala-lang.modules.scala-java8-compat_2.13-0.9.0.jar
    │   ├── org.scala-lang.modules.scala-parallel-collections_2.13-0.2.0.jar
    │   ├── org.scala-lang.modules.scala-xml_2.13-1.2.0.jar
    │   ├── org.scala-lang.scala-compiler-2.13.0.jar
    │   ├── org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.13.0.jar
    │   ├── org.scala-lang.scala-reflect-2.13.0.jar
    │   ├── org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
    │   ├── org.slf4j.slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
    │   ├── org.typelevel.cats-core_2.13-2.0.0.jar
    │   ├── org.typelevel.cats-effect_2.13-2.0.0.jar
    │   ├── org.typelevel.cats-kernel_2.13-2.0.0.jar
    │   ├── org.typelevel.cats-macros_2.13-2.0.0.jar
    │   ├── org.typelevel.jawn-parser_2.13-0.14.2.jar
    │   ├── org.yaml.snakeyaml-1.15.jar
    │   └── org.zeroturnaround.zt-zip-1.13.jar
    ├── schema-extender
    │   ├── bin
    │   │   ├── schema-extender
    │   │   └── schema-extender.bat
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   ├── com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations-2.10.1.jar
    │   │   ├── com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.10.1.jar
    │   │   ├── com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar
    │   │   ├── com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.1.jar
    │   │   ├── com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.1.jar
    │   │   ├── com.github.pathikrit.better-files_2.12-3.8.0.jar
    │   │   ├── com.github.scopt.scopt_2.12-3.7.1.jar
    │   │   ├── com.lihaoyi.geny_2.12-0.4.2.jar
    │   │   ├── com.lihaoyi.ujson_2.12-0.9.5.jar
    │   │   ├── com.lihaoyi.upickle-core_2.12-0.9.5.jar
    │   │   ├── com.typesafe.play.play-functional_2.12-2.8.1.jar
    │   │   ├── com.typesafe.play.play-json_2.12-2.8.1.jar
    │   │   ├── io.shiftleft.overflowdb-codegen_2.12-1.12.jar
    │   │   ├── joda-time.joda-time-2.10.5.jar
    │   │   ├── org.scala-lang.modules.scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.0.0.jar
    │   │   ├── org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.12.11.jar
    │   │   ├── org.scala-lang.scala-reflect-2.12.11.jar
    │   │   ├── org.slf4j.slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
    │   │   ├── org.zeroturnaround.zt-zip-1.14.jar
    │   │   └── schema-extender.schema-extender-9c0397efa3eb6787d7dd1ae104bab1379a6816e8.jar
    │   └── schemas
    │       ├── base.json
    │       ├── closure.json
    │       ├── dependency.json
    │       ├── dom.json
    │       ├── dynamicCalls.json
    │       ├── enhancements-internal.json
    │       ├── enhancements.json
    │       ├── flow.json
    │       ├── java-specific.json
    │       ├── operators.json
    │       ├── securityprofile.json
    │       ├── sensitivedata.json
    │       ├── source-specific.json
    │       └── splitting.json
    └── schema-extender.sh
```

graph-for-funcs.sc:

```
/* graph-for-funcs.scala

   This script returns a Json representation of the graph resulting in combining the
   AST, CGF, and PDG for each method contained in the currently loaded CPG.

   Input: A valid CPG
   Output: Json

   Running the Script
   ------------------
   see: README.md

   The JSON generated has the following keys:

   "functions": Array of all methods contained in the currently loaded CPG
     |_ "function": Method name as String
     |_ "id": Method id as String (String representation of the underlying Method node)
     |_ "AST": see ast-for-funcs script
     |_ "CFG": see cfg-for-funcs script
     |_ "PDG": see pdg-for-funcs script
 */

import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
import io.circe.{Encoder, Json}

import io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language.types.expressions.generalizations.CfgNode
import io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.EdgeTypes
import io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.NodeTypes
import io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.nodes
import io.shiftleft.dataflowengine.language._
import io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language._
import io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language.types.expressions.Call
import io.shiftleft.semanticcpg.language.types.structure.Local
import io.shiftleft.codepropertygraph.generated.nodes.MethodParameterIn

import gremlin.scala._
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Edge
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty

final case class GraphForFuncsFunction(function: String,
                                       file: String,
                                       id: String,
                                       AST: List[nodes.AstNode],
                                       CFG: List[nodes.AstNode],
                                       PDG: List[nodes.AstNode])
final case class GraphForFuncsResult(functions: List[GraphForFuncsFunction])

implicit val encodeEdge: Encoder[Edge] =
  (edge: Edge) =>
    Json.obj(
      ("id", Json.fromString(edge.toString)),
      ("in", Json.fromString(edge.inVertex().toString)),
      ("out", Json.fromString(edge.outVertex().toString))
    )

implicit val encodeNode: Encoder[nodes.AstNode] =
  (node: nodes.AstNode) =>
    Json.obj(
      ("id", Json.fromString(node.toString)),
      ("edges",
        Json.fromValues((node.inE("AST", "CFG").l ++ node.outE("AST", "CFG").l).map(_.asJson))),
      ("properties", Json.fromValues(node.properties().asScala.toList.map { p: VertexProperty[_] =>
        Json.obj(
          ("key", Json.fromString(p.key())),
          ("value", Json.fromString(p.value().toString))
        )
      }))
    )

implicit val encodeFuncFunction: Encoder[GraphForFuncsFunction] = deriveEncoder
implicit val encodeFuncResult: Encoder[GraphForFuncsResult] = deriveEncoder

@main def main(): Json = {
  GraphForFuncsResult(
    cpg.method.map { method =>
      val methodName = method.fullName
      val methodFile = method.location.filename
      val methodId = method.toString

      val astChildren = method.astMinusRoot.l

      val cfgChildren = new NodeSteps(
        method.out(EdgeTypes.CONTAINS).filterOnEnd(_.isInstanceOf[nodes.CfgNode]).cast[nodes.CfgNode]
      ).l

      val local = new NodeSteps(
        method
          .out(EdgeTypes.CONTAINS)
          .hasLabel(NodeTypes.BLOCK)
          .out(EdgeTypes.AST)
          .hasLabel(NodeTypes.LOCAL)
          .cast[nodes.Local])
      val sink = local.evalType(".*").referencingIdentifiers.dedup
      val source = new NodeSteps(method.out(EdgeTypes.CONTAINS).hasLabel(NodeTypes.CALL).cast[nodes.Call]).nameNot("<operator>.*").dedup

      val pdgChildren = sink
        .reachableByFlows(source)
        .l
        .flatMap { path =>
          path.elements
            .map {
              case trackingPoint @ (_: MethodParameterIn) => trackingPoint.start.method.head
              case trackingPoint                          => trackingPoint.cfgNode
            }
        }
        .filter(_.toString != methodId)

      GraphForFuncsFunction(methodName, methodFile, methodId, astChildren, cfgChildren, pdgChildren.distinct)
    }.l
  ).asJson
}
```

Comment: It seems they renamed the `io.shiftleft.dataflowengine` package to `io.shiftleft.dataflowengineoss` (and probably other changes).

Comment: @GáborBakosG，thanks a lot, that's the case!